# How can I specify a column using a #line directive?

Tags: c#, code-generation, dsl

In C#, you can use `#line` directives in generated code to change how errors are reported and how debugging happens.

For example, this razor code:

```
@model Foo
@{
    var foo = ViewBag.Foo;
}
```

May generate a #line directive like so:

```
#line 2 "project\foo.cshtml"
    var foo = ViewBag.Foo;
#line hidden
```

However, this breaks down when two C# expressions are on the same line, like this:

```
<img width="@width" height="@height" />
```

Producing `#line` directives like so:

```
#line 40
width
#line hidden
...
#line 40
height
#line hidden
```

How can I specify the column along with a line directive?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick I came up with:

Pad your code with spaces, so that the columns line up, so

```
<img width="@width" height="@height" />
```

becomes

```
#line 40
             width
#line hidden
...
#line 40
                             height
#line hidden
```

This trick works both for compiler errors and for debugging within Visual Studio.